# Bullet hinge constraint, force appliance to achieve a clip like feature

Tags: physics, physics-engine, bulletphysics

Is it possible, and if yes, how do I apply force in Bullet, if I have two objects connected with a hinge constraint and something is making them to open up a bit more?
So is it possible to give some kind of resistance force to the hinge constraint?

1. example: *a clip*
2. example: *I have a V like shape, to which from the open part I push something that makes the V wider. But now I need to apply force on the object from the two legs of V.*

(If relevant: *Bullet version: bullet-2.82-r2704*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bullet has a function to apply force to rigid bodies:
void btRigidBody::applyForce(const btVector3 &force, const btVector3 &rel_pos)

> *Reference: 
>  http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtRigidBody.html#af016720c45cf7ccaf8701d81a28319d9*

**First**, to achieve the clip like hinge constraint, you have to create a **hinge constraint**.

> *Reference: 
>  http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Constraints#Hinge*

**Next**, you have to apply an **angular force** to both legs with opposite direction. So the force that pulls the clips together depends on the angle between the two "legs".

(In addition, you can set a limit for the hinge constraint to stop it at a specified angle).